# How to export an html table saved in a string variable to an excel file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, excel

I'm trying to save an Html table to an excel file, the issue is that I have the table saved as a string variable inside an script in a cshtml file.

I have the next code in C# file:

```
public ActionResult show_schedules(int support, DateTime ini, DateTime fin)
        {
//-------------------------            
//Some code to obtain data of the table
//-------------------------           
            var table = "<table id=\"tabla1\" class=\"table table-condensed table-bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
            var encabezado = "<tr class=\"theader\" bgcolor=\"#4EB0F0\"><th class=\"sticky\" nowrap style=\"border: 1px solid black; left: 0; top: auto; width: 100px; position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; background-color: #4EB0F0;\">" +
                                "Date</th><th nowrap style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">Day</th>";
            var body_th = "";
            var schedule = "";
            foreach (var us in users)
            {
                body_th = body_th + "<th nowrap style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" + us.UserName + "</th>";
            }
            //theader end

            encabezado = encabezado + body_th + "</tr>";
//-------------------------            
//Some more code to fill the table
//-------------------------  
                schedule = schedule + "</tr>";
                if (lastMonday.DayOfWeek == 0)
                {
                    schedule = schedule + encabezado;
                }
                lastMonday = lastMonday.AddDays(1);

            }
            table = table + encabezado + schedule + "</table>";

//------------------------------
//Return of the final table (which is a whole string)
//------------------------------
            return Json(table, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

        }
```

then I call this Action from the view (cshtml) in a script like this:

```
<script>
$("#show").click(function () {
        var data = {
            support: $("#support").val(),
            ini: $("#shift_date_ini").val(),
            fin: $("#shift_date_end").val()
        }
        $.ajax({

            url: '/Home/show_schedules',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
            },
            success: function (r) {

//-------------
//--- HERE I APPEND THE RESULT TO THE HTML CODE IN THE schedule PLACE                         
                result = r; 
                $("#schedule").empty();
                $("#schedule").append(r);

                //console.log("Respuesta: " + result)


            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert('responseText:' + xhr.responseText)
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

I understand that I have the html table saved as a string in the local variable *result*, but I don't know how to convert that table into an excel file.

It would really help me to know how to do that, I've tried a couple of things but nothing works.

Comment: If you want to produce an Excel file, then surely a better idea would be to send the data to the server, and have the server produce an actual Excel file (as opposed to some HTML) which can then be downloaded. There are free libraries for .NET you can use to generate proper Excel files.

Comment: (And also, as a general rule, don't use AJAX to try and download files. As you've discovered, it's a PITA. If you need to use JavaScript to trigger the download, use window.location or window.open to cause the browser to visit the URL directly, which will then cause the file data to be downloaded in the normal way (assuming the server responds with file data and the correct headers, of course)).